# Google Chrome Text Size Remains Constant on the page

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

So I've come across an issue with a site today regarding strange behavior with Google Chrome.  Essentially when the end user uses the built in "CTRL +/ CTRL -" functions to change the text size on the page, the images get bigger and all, but the text size remains constant.  I've gone over the markup and css and can't find anything that would cause this.  The site behaves as expected when the equivalent functions are used in Firefox and I.E. so I am wondering if anyone has any idea what would cause this?

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I should look for here?

Comment: Fancy giving us a link to the page - or are we supposed to guess ?

Comment: look for "-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;" in your css. And yes, post a link to the page.

Comment: Well I was hoping that maybe their was just a generally well known cause I wasn't aware of. I'd prefer to check that our client and the like would be alright with me sharing the link in relation to the problem before I did so.  I'll check and update the question accordingly.

Comment: If a link cannot be provided, you can do a process of elimination within Chrome's inspector by disabling specific CSS properties. Right click on the text, select Inspect Element and begin working in the area to the right of the inspector.

Comment: @3rror404 - didn't catch it (and to be honest didn't know to look for it), but it looks like that's what caused it.  If you can post this as an answer I'll mark it correct so you get the points.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
```

in your CSS.

If it exists, there's your problem. Change it to:

```
-webkit-text-size-adjust: auto;
```

or remove the reference altogether (it should default to auto).

Comment: Why does such a horribly anti-accessible setting exist?!!?